# No value given for one or more required parameters asp.net error

Tags: asp.net, parameters, detailsview

I'm having a problem with my code that I've been trying to fix for hours now. Basically, the goal of the program is for users to log in, then they can fill in basically a movie review page. Theoretically every user is only allowed to leave one review for each movie - though I haven't gotten to the validation for that yet. Right now, it just keeps saying that there's no value given for one of the parameters so if anyone could help out that would be amazing.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

<asp:GridView ID="GridReview" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="movieid" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
<Columns> <asp:BoundField DataField="movietitle" HeaderText="movietitle" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="false" SortExpression="movietitle" />

<asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="User" SortExpression="Username" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="review" HeaderText="Review" SortExpression="review" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="rating" HeaderText="Rating" SortExpression="rating" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="movieid" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DefaultMode="Insert" Height="50px" Width="125px" OnItemInserted="DetailsView1_ItemInserted">
<Fields>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MovieTitle" SortExpression="Movieid">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceW2" DataTextField="MovieTitle" DataValueField="MovieId"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceW2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database1connectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database1connectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [MovieID], [MovieTitle] FROM [movies_table] ORDER BY [Movietitle]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
</ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="rating" HeaderText="rating" SortExpression="rating" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="review" HeaderText="review" SortExpression="review" />

<asp:CommandField ShowInsertButton="True" />
</Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>

</div>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database1ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="select * from REVIEW_TABLE where (movieid = ?)" InsertCommand="insert [REVIEW_TABLE]
([Username], [MovieID], [MovieTitle], [Rating], [Review])
values (?,?,?,?,?)" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database1ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" >

<InsertParameters>
<asp:SessionParameter Name="Username" SessionField="Username" Type="String" />
<asp:Parameter Name="movieid" Type="String" />
<asp:Parameter Name="movietitle" Type="String" />
<asp:Parameter Name="rating" Type="String" />
<asp:Parameter Name="review" Type="String" />
</InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>


<asp:Label ID="LabelError" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</form>
```

Here's the code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["firstname"] == null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
        Session["UserName"] = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    }
}

protected void DetailsView1_ItemInserted(object sender, DetailsViewInsertedEventArgs e)
{
    GridReview.DataBind();
}
```

and here's the error I keep getting

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> No value given for one or more required parameters.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: No value given for one or more required parameters.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [OleDbException (0x80040e10): No value given for one or more required parameters.]
>
> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr) +1144656
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult) +247
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult) +208
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult) +58
>          System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +162
>          System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +110
>          System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +9
>          System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +139
>          System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +136
>          System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable) +86
>          System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +1474
>          System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +22
>          System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +143
>          System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +74
>          System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind() +9
>          System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +114
>          System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls() +75
>          System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +92
>          System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +42
>          System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
>          System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
>          System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +883

Answer (score 0):

Its a case of spelling mistake.
The session variable is named with **N** in capital while retrieval in aspx is in lower case

In aspx

```
<asp:SessionParameter Name="Username" SessionField="Username" Type="String" />
```

In code behind

```
Session["UserName"] = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

Besides, once the Response.Redirect, the session setting will not get executed.

How's your login page redirecting back to referrer and whether its setting the **firstname** variable or not is also required to be checked, as it affects the retrieval of **UserName** from session.

You need to place a debugger in this line to identify the actual issue. However, the variable name needs correction first (Better use a constant file to store such identifiers)